# Tailwind CSS only generating some classes in Yew app

Tags: tailwind-css, trunk, yew

I've been trying include tailwind css into a simple Rust wasm frontend using the yew framework serving the app with trunk.

I installed tailwind v3.4.1 using npm as per the [instructions here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation).

My tailwind config is:

```
module.exports = {
    content: [
        "src/**/*.rs",
        "index.html"
    ],
    presets: [],
    darkMode: 'media', // or 'class'
    theme: {
    },
    variants: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
};
```

My application is a single rust file:

```
use yew::prelude::*;

#[function_component]
fn App() -> Html {
    html! {
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="h-[50%] bg-purple-600">{"Row 1"}</div>
            <div class="bg-green-600 text-purple-900">{"Row 2"}</div>
        </div>
    }
}

fn main() {
    yew::Renderer::<App>::new().render();
}
```

In the index.html I've included the following tag:

`<link data-trunk rel="tailwind-css" href="src/tailwind.css"/>`

And the contents of the linked `src/tailwind.css` file:

```
@config "../tailwind.config.js"
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

When I serve my application via `trunk serve` it generates the css in my `dist` directory however this compiled css file only includes the `h-[50%]` class definition and none of the other classes.

```
.h-\[50\%\] {
  height: 50%
}
```

I think my setup is fine for incorporating tailwind with trunk and rust/yew and is a problem with my tailwind configuration. Any help solving this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider removing the `presets` key in the Tailwind configuration.

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/presets#disabling-the-default-configuration), having a `presets` property set to an empty array value disables inheritance of the default Tailwind configuration, meaning no values exist for any dynamically-registered utility classes. This means that the default colors `purple.600`, `green.600` and `purple.900` that have tried to use via `bg-purple-600`, `bg-green-600` and `text-purple-900` respectively do not exist in the resolved Tailwind configuration.

Furthermore, `d-flex` and `flex-column` are not Tailwind classes either. You may have meant `flex` and `flex-col` respectively.